# PostGIS: How to efficiently query a large number of polygons in chunks?

Tags: postgis

I am developing a CAD program that allows a user to pan around very large layers of polygons. If the user is zoomed out, for example, then I may need to render millions of polygons. I would like to slowly draw this scene for the user by rendering a few polygons every frame, but that means I will need a query that is able select a rectangular area of polygons from a PostGIS database in chunks. Here is the table and index that I'm using:

```
create table POLYGON(ID serial8 primary key,
    LAYER_ID bigint not null,
    GEOM geometry(polygon,0) not null);

create index on POLYGON using gist(LAYER_ID, GEOM);
```

I want to perform the following query:

```
select POLYGON.ID, ST_AsBinary(POLYGON.GEOM) from POLYGON 
where LAYER_ID = ? and (ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 0) && GEOM);
```

But that query may take a very long time and return a large number of results. Is there some way I can divide this huge query into smaller queries?

I considered using "offset" and "limit", but I don't think that will work, because my results are not ordered. Also, as far as "offset", I believe that postgres still has to query everything that it is skipping.

I could try dividing the polygons into groups myself, so that I could retrieve one group at a time, but hasn't the "gist" index already internally partitioned my geometries in some way? I don't want to build another system on top of the "gist" index unless I absolutely have to.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.